# Accessing ViewModel properties in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have seen a lot of trivial examples of accessing ViewModel properties in the view. What I need is traverse through an array (one of the properties is an array) and display them in the table..

I pass the following ViewModel to my view:

```
  public class myViewModel
    {

        public List<SomeObject> listofObjects {get;set}

        //other properties....       

    }

    public class SomeObject {
         public string Id {get;set;}
         public string Name {get; set;}
         public string Someotherprop {get; set;}
    }
```

Question # 1: How do I loop through the listOfObjects and display all their properties in the table? I am using asp.net mvc 3 with Razor.

Question # 2: How do I make this array accessible in my JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sarsnake,

question 1: just simple foreach in razor will do the job

in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeObject>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
   <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</div>
}
```

question 2: in the controller, use JsonResult to return Json representation of that array. Then you should be able to use javsacript to consume the object

Comment: well, I pass ViewModel...so it would be (var item in Model.listOfObjects)?

Comment: it really depends on what object do you pass to the view as example above i passed the array only to the view. in your case, the model declaration will be @model myViewModel